# org.chromium.chrome FATAL:jni_android.cc(249) when "targetSdkVersion = 30"

Tags: chromium, targetsdkversion

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/tree/master/chrome/android

When "targetSdkVersion = 30":

2022-02-22 13:21:26.204 12519-12519/org.chromium.chrome A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report

2022-02-22 13:21:26.485 12519-12519/org.chromium.chrome A/libc: Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 12519 (chromium.chrome), pid 12519 (chromium.chrome)

2022-02-22 13:21:26.597 15181-15181/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(249)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report

How do I stop the crash please?